# Ms Access - Button with code doesn't work to send email

Tags: email, ms-access

I have this code set in access, but no email is sending upon clicking the button on the form. I have outlook open. When i click the button on the form, i can't see anything that actually happens. I want the email address to be equal to the value in [text1], and I am trying to make the subject include a fixed message plus the input from [text2]. Even without these variables, I can't get this to work

```
Public Sub Command495_Click()
Dim mailto As String
Dim ccto As String
Dim bccto As String
mailto = [text1]
ccto = ""
bccto = ""
emailmsg = "trial"
mailsub = [text2] & ", Does this work?"
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObjectType, , acFormattxt, mailto, ccto, bccto, mailsubj, emailmsg, True


End Sub
```

I have checked to make sure the onclick property shows event procedure. I am stuck, please help!

Comment: So I know that this needs to be public, and that I have typo in code (asFormat should be acFormat). I'm learning so please be patient. All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions and a modified version of your code.

- ALWAYS use Option Explicit and compile your module before testing. You had a number of variables that were not defined and incorrect spelling of some options.
- NEVER bypass errors when testing (get rid of your "On Error Resume Next") That's why you never saw an error.
- Look for every place I entered ">>>" and address that issue.
- Always explicitly define your variables and use the proper Type. Removes all doubt of what/where something is.

  Option Compare Database
  Option Explicit
  Public Sub Command495_Click()
  Dim mailto      As String
  Dim ccto        As String
  Dim bccto       As String
  Dim emailmsg    As String
  Dim mailsub     As String

  ```
  mailto = [Text1]            ' >>> Where is [Text1]?? Remove for testing
  ccto = ""
  bccto = ""
  emailmsg = "trial"
  mailsub = [Text2] & ", Does this work?"     ' >>> Where is [Text2]??  Remove for testing
  ' >>> Bad idea to ignore errors when testing!!
  On Error Resume Next
  '>>> Following line had: (1) 'acSendNoObjectType' which is incorrect; (2) mailsubj, which is undefined
  DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , acFormatTXT, mailto, ccto, bccto, mailsub, emailmsg, True
  ```

  End Sub

Comment: Thanks for the tip to compile- helped a bunch. Also, I did not have the reference to outlook library enabled- that solved my issue between the two. Thanks!